# How to use node.js methods in Jade template within Wintersmith

Tags: node.js, pug, wintersmith

I have asked google like million times and haven't got any concrete answers... I would like to use, say, following code in the jade template... however it gives an error on the first line... Please could you point me to the right direction... Thanks in advance!!

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.unlink('/tmp/hello', function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
});
```

Comment: What error does it give? Just to double-check: did you write that code inside your .jade template file or somewhere else?

Comment: Also please note that if you want get answers and get things done, make sure you stick with the question, comment and update as necessary. Applies to all software development work in general as well :)

Comment: Why are you writing code like this in a jade template in the first place? You put your presentation in the template, and then this sort of thing would be in some sort of .js file. From what little I just read of Wintersmith, it is a static site generator, so your question seems akin to asking about how you use a golf club to cook a casserole.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing hyphens to escape your template code to JavaScript. Add a hyphen to each line for starters.

```
- var something = 0; // example!
```

Source: [Jade reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#code)

Second, @barry-johnson is right to point out your Node code probably belongs somewhere else. It looks like you're trying to clean up a directory during the build. There are other, better ways to accomplish this. I suggest taking a look at the [Writing Plugins page](https://github.com/jnordberg/wintersmith/wiki/Writing-plugins) for more info.

If that doesn't suit you, please describe in more detail what you're trying to accomplish for better guidance. I hope that helps!